# How do I disable users in Teamcity?

Tags: teamcity

If somebody has left my firm, how do I disable their account in Teamcity. I only see a delete option. I'll lose the configurations set by the user if I delete him right?

Is there a disable/Deactivate user option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to disable a user. You can watch/vote for the corresponding [issue in the bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-22731)

The options you have now are:

- Remove all roles/permissions of a user
- Change user's password
- Delete the user. This will not delete user's created items (projects, configurations, etc). The deleted user will be shown as 'unknown' on the UI